Avoiding/Accepting Cookies with Selenium and Python
I am making a python program with selenium to automatically interact with a web page. The version of Selenium is 4.1.3 and that of Chrome is 124.
The problem occurs when when I enter the page I get the cookies popup, and I cannot find the button using the code to click. I have tried this here that I found in StackOverflow solutions but it didn't work:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
s = Service(r"chromedriver.exe")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-cookies")

# start driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

# go to page
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://deepai.org/machine-learning-model/fantasy-world-generator')

# find accept cookies button
button= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="notice"]/div[3]/div[2]/button')
button.click()
# find textarea by placeholder
textarea = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('textarea[placeholder="Enter your prompt"]')

# enter a monster in textarea
textarea.send_keys('A monster')

# button search

hdButton = driver.find_element_by_id("modelHdButton")
hdButton.click()

button = driver.find_element_by_id("modelSubmitButton")
button.click()

# close controller
driver.quit()

I get the path of the element using the chrome console F12, copy XPath option, so it should not be wrong.
I have tried with JSPath and others paths in the options list and it hasn't worked either.
I also tried deactivating the options parameter of the webdriver, putting only driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s).
It should be able to click the button, or at least find it, but it can't do either.

I don't get a cookie popup... or any other popup when I navigate to that page

I get but I solved it.

It may sound silly, but I turned out that the problem is that the cookies were inside an iframe, which seems to be treated as a different document than the page, at least at the route level.
All I had to do was use the function:driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_id").
And use the normal paths.
